# Quicksort algorithm on an array, always choose the last element as pivot

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Does this quicksort implementation always correctly choose the last element of the array as the pivot?

```
public class lab3q3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = {8, 2, 5, 3, 9, 4, 7, 6, 1};

        quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

        for (int i : array) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    private static void quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        if (end <= start) return; // Base case

        int pivotIndex = partition(array, start, end);
        quickSort(array, start, pivotIndex - 1);
        quickSort(array, pivotIndex + 1, end);
    }

    private static int partition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        int pivotValue = array[end]; // Choose the last element as the pivot
        int i = start - 1;

        for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
            if (array[j] <= pivotValue) {
                i++;
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a statement that takes the last element as pivot, with a comment next to it. What makes you doubt? Why this question?

Comment: im just in the process of learning data structures and algorithm so i wanted another opinion that it does always uses the last elemt as the pivot every time

Comment: OK, but asking for another opinion for something that works is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. You could check Wikipedia and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code is correct according to the implementation of the QuickSort algorithm and also chooses the last element as the pivot.

However, the efficiency of your algorithm may be affected by this in cases where the input array is already sorted or nearly sorted, tending to a complexity of O(n²). Consider this when choosing your pivot, be it the first element of the array, a middle element, or a random element.

Answer (score -1):

add random

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] array = {8, 2, 5, 3, 9, 4, 7, 6, 1,9};

    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}

private static void quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    if (end <= start) return; // Base case

    int pivotIndex = partition(array, start, end);
    quickSort(array, start, pivotIndex - 1);
    quickSort(array, pivotIndex + 1, end);
}

private static int partition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int random = start+((int) ((end-start) * Math.random()));
    int cur =array[random];
    array[random] = array[end];
    array[end] = cur;

    int pivotValue = array[end]; // Choose the last element as the pivot
    int i = start - 1;

    for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivotValue) {
            i++;
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about correctness.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).